# screen flickers when using navigator with routes defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the initialRoute and the routes setup on the main.dart file, When I try to use one of the routes, I get pushed to that route successfully,  but I notice screen flickering on that page.
Here is my main.dart file -

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await _configureAmplify();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (BuildContext context) => const BolWelcome(),
        '/authentication': (BuildContext context) => const Authentication(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

This is how I got the navigator setup on the BolWelcome Widget currently.

void initState() {
super.initState();

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
  setState(() {
     Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
       context,
       '/authentication',
       ModalRoute.withName('/'),
    );
  });
});
```

}

I was using the navigator in a different way before which worked as expected and I never noticed any screen flickering. What could be the reason?

void initState() {
super.initState();

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Authentication()),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Using a `Timer` to navigate between routes rapidly in a short time interval can cause screen flickering due to rapid transitions. Please use`Future.delayed` the initial navigation using `addPostFrameCallback` to avoid this kind of issue.

Please modify your code as below:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        '/authentication',
        (route) => false,
      );
    });
  });
}
```

you are not updating any state within the `addPostFrameCallback` method it means no need to use `setState()` in that block.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added background color to the main container/scaffold.